# a simple redirect code with dropdown menu that does not return an error

Tags: javascript

the objective is to redirect the user according to the option chosen in the drop-down menu. ex. if user chose apple redirect user to apple.html page when he hit SUBMIT button.

I know it's basic but don't curse me my mother =]

all the best.

```
<body>
    <form  name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select>
        <option id="apple">Apple</option>
        <option id="orange">Orange</option>
        <option id="pineapple">Pineapple</option> 
        <option id="banana" selected>Banana</option>
      </select>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
    
    </p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSubmitForm(e){   
        
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.target)
        if(document.getElementById("apple").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="apple.html";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("pineapple").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="pineapple.html";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("orange").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="orange.html";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("banana").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="banana.html";
        }      
    }

        
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        
    e.preventDefault();
        
    if(document.getElementById("apple").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="apple.html";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("pineapple").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="pineapple.html";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("orange").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="orange.html";
        }
        else (document.getElementById("banana").selected ==true)
        {
        location.href ="banana.html";
        }
    
});
</script>
</body>
```

I already spent hours researching but my IQ is 60. Anyone who can help has my eternal gratitude.

Comment: `else (document.getElementById("banana").selected ==true)` should be `else if (document.getElementById("banana").selected ==true)`

Answer (score 1):

The option elements should have a value attribute and the select element should have a name attribute.

In the submit callback function `e.target` refer to the form and then you can get the select element by it's name and the value will be the value of the selected option.

```js
document.forms.myform.addEventListener("submit", e =>  {
  e.preventDefault();
  location.href = `${e.target.fruit.value}.html`;
});
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <select name="fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana" selected>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
  </p>
</form>
```

An alternative could be to actually use the GET request of the form to navigate to the "fruit" page. Instead of using the `location.href` and the `e.preventDefault()` each time the select element changes you can set the `action` attribute on the form and then just let the form submit as default.

```js
document.forms.myform.fruit.addEventListener("change", e =>  {
  e.target.form.action = `${e.target.form.fruit.value}.html`;
});
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="banana.html">
  <select name="fruit">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="pineapple">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="banana" selected>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">save</button>
  </p>
</form>
```